# Powershell: gci filter with compact output

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to find files recursively, and for that I am using

```
> gci -name -filter *.py -r
```

Option `-name` gives only the file name, to get one line per item found, as required. But the items that I get as output show only the relative path, e.g.

```
python\scr.py
```

(the current dir is `C:\python`) while a similar command in `cmd.exe`

```
> where /r . *.py
```

gives

```
C:\data\python\scr.py
```

as wanted.

Is there any way of getting this with `gci`?

I would like to minimize piping/greping with regex/the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're averse to piping, since it is arguably the most imporant feature of PowerShell, but I would leave out the  `-name` parameter. Then, use `Select-Object` (alias, `select`) to get the FullName of the FileInfo object, and use the `-expand` switch to output only the string value of the FullName property. If you want to keep it short, you can also leave out `-filter` and add '`.`', since the second positional parameter is `-Filter`.

```
gci . *.py -r| select -exp fullname
```

Or use `Foreach-Object` (alias, `%` or `foreach`), and output the FullName.

```
gci . *.py -r| % {$_.FullName}
```

Comment: `gci -filter *.py -r| select -expand fullname` is probably cleaner than your second option which is probably what OP's looking for.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right @zdan. I'll add that switch to the first example.

Comment: Both options work ok.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using piping, you can use the following:

```
(gci -filter *.py -recurse).FullName
```

Comment: This didn't work, at the same prompt where both options given by Rynant work.

Comment: @sancho.s, the answer should work for PowerShell v3 and up.

Comment: @Rynant - That's probably the reason, I think I have v2 (as per `>$PSVersionTable.psversion`)